# Using the CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW clause in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_NAME BUILD IMMEDIATE AS
<SQL Query>
```

So I followed this example in my lecture. But it doesn't work when I run it in oracle. When I typed it in notepad++ with the file saved as .sql, the `MATERIALIZED` and `BUILD` parts didn't come out as bold, blue font like it should in Notepad++. I did some research online and I found that it all says the statement I am using is correct. But the SQL command line and Notepad++ say otherwise. I got `ORA-00922: Missing or invalid option` error in the prompt. Anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: "*and how to fix it?*" - read the manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`create materialized view` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6002.htm#i2145767) doesn't support the `or replace` option that you can use with a normal view.

> ```
> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW [ schema. ] materialized_view
>   [ OF [ schema. ] object_type ]
>   [ ( { scoped_table_ref_constraint
>       | column_alias [ENCRYPT [encryption_spec]]
>       }
>       [, { scoped_table_ref_constraint
>          | column_alias [ENCRYPT [encryption_spec]]
>          }
>       ]...
>     )
>   ]
>   { ON PREBUILT TABLE
>     [ { WITH | WITHOUT } REDUCED PRECISION ]
>   | physical_properties materialized_view_props
>   }
>   [ USING INDEX
>     [ physical_attributes_clause
>     | TABLESPACE tablespace
>     ]...
>   | USING NO INDEX
>   ]
>   [ create_mv_refresh ]
>   [ FOR UPDATE ]
>   [ { DISABLE | ENABLE } QUERY REWRITE ]
> AS subquery ;
> ```

If the MV already exists you need to drop it before creating it again, without that invalid clause.

```
DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_NAME;
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_NAME BUILD IMMEDIATE AS
<SQL Query>
```